# Create javascript file at runtime with dynamic content and call function

Tags: javascript, dynamic, sapui5

I have some data stored in the backend. This data looks like that.

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        testFunc: function() {
            alert("function");
        }
    };
});
```

Now I want to call the above function "testFunc()" at runtime, like:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller","...pfad.to.function], 
function(Controller, Function) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("CONT", {
        onInit: function() ;
           Function.testFunc();
        },
    })
});
```

But I only get the above string at runtime . 
The Background:

The developer has an editor. In this editor he is writing the function code. Like above. When he is finished, the code is stored to the backend. When the application is starting, the code will fetched from the backend and proceed in frontend. So only at this time I know the code and have to run it dynamically. An furthermore, I need the possibility to debug. So I need to load the whole script file.

Is there a way to manage this?

Rg. Joerg

Comment: That seems like a bad design idea. How is your script code stored, as string? Or as a file?

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable in the controller scope to store the Function you pass as parameter when instantiating it:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "...pfad.to.function",
], function (Controller, Function) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("CONT", {

        //This variable stores the object you return in your module
        myObjectWithFunction: Function, 

        onInit: function() ;
            this.myObjectWithFunction.testFunc();
        }
    });
});
```

Take a look at the ["Custom Formatters" documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de)... it's basically the same concept

Comment: Thanks Rafael, but the first question arise is. How to create this object "myObjectWithFunction". I do not have a static file in the project.

Comment: And the second is. I do not want to be so far from the standard procedure. So this is not the way to work according to WEBIDE or Eclipse. There must be another way.  For my understanding, I would like to add the resources to my project prgramatically and when call it in the standard way.

Comment: sidenote; variable name `Function` is already part of native JS, try calling it something else